# NumberFormatException Spring

Tags: java, spring, exception

Below code...

```
    @GetMapping("/brian/{number}")
    public String getBrianMessage(@PathVariable int number) throws NumberFormatException {
        try {
            logList.add(number);
            String stringList = logList.toString();
            return "List is " + stringList;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e){
            int newCount= 999;
            logList.add(newCount);
            String stringList = logList.toString();
            return "List is " + stringList;
        }
    }
```

When going to the url i would like the integer stored in a list. This works fine when you use a valid integer value. I want the ability to default the value to 999 when a string is supplied. So, if i go to /brian/string it should add 999 to the list and return it. This is not working and I'm getting the same error as before I added the exception handling

Comment: Your argument is of type `int`. How could Spring store, for example, "abcd" in a variable of type `int`? If you want to accept a String, then change the type of the variable to String, and check if it can be parsed to an int by yourself, in the method.

Comment: I'm just trying to learn exception handling a little better. So I'm guessing it's not even making it to the try statement as the argument being an integer is what's causing the error. hence we are then NEVER catching the exception?

Comment: You got it. Spring wants to call your method. Your method needs an int. It can't possibly transform abcd to an int. So it throws an exception and never calls your method. By typing the variable as int, you implcitly told Spring: reject any value that can't be pasred as an int.